# iframe redirecting to https site

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have

```
<iframe src="https://path/to/site" width="300" />
```

My existing site is also over https.

But i get the error

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://path/to/site' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://path/to/site'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

But the src has https in the iframe.

How to resolve this?

Comment: Presumably that site is redirecting from HTTPS to HTTP.

Comment: Yes original site is https but the iframe also has src as https then why am i getting this error ?

Comment: Give us the actual URL of the site you are trying to embed, then we can see if it is due to a redirect or not.